# Rails select query to MSSQL returns -1:Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-server-2008

I have Rails connected to an external MSSQL database. In database.yml the adapter is sqlserver.

The code for the query:

```
class External < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.select_all_entries
      external_connection_hash = configurations["external_DB"]
      establish_connection external_connection_hash
      con = connection()

      side = con.execute("Select * from dbo.BBOrders").fetch_row;
      return side
   end
end
```

And I get the error - undefined method "fetch_row" for -1:Fixnum

The database info is correct. I tried to access a different table and get the same answer, but if I access a table with no entries, it throws another exception, so it is connecting but not giving the values. Any ideas?

**EDIT** database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  dsn: K_Connection
  #dsn: mydsn
  mode: odbc
  #mode: dblib
  encoding: utf8
  database: KTrade
  host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  username: tr
  password: tr2
```

Comment: Is this the primary database for you app? Or is this a secondary database you're trying to establish a connection to?

Comment: It is my primary database. But how would that change anything?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set up a Model class to establish a database connection.

Define your database in database.yml, get rid of the class External and ActiveRecord::Base will establish the connection when you load rails (either with rails s or rails c)

In database.yml you're telling active record that you're using the sqlserver adapter, so that means you should have this gem in your Gemfile: https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter

The convention for defining Model classes in Rails is to define it like a resource.  Your have a table name called dbo.BBorders.  Kind of a weird name, it should probably just be "bb_orders" or "orders." Then your model name is:

```
class BbOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  #pay attention to capitalization and singularity/plurality
  #convention is for table name be the plural, camel cased version of the model name
  #BbOrder is the model name. bb_orders is the table name
end
```

or

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

If your table name MUST be "dbo.BBOrders" then you can override the default table name that Rails is expecting:

```
class BbOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "dbo.BBOrders"
end
```

Once you have a model defined & associated with a table, you can query it like so from the console:

```
BbOrder.all

ActiveRecord will generate the query:
"select * from bb_orders" (or whatever the table name is)
```

If you really want to write custom queries, you can with:

```
BbOrder.connection.execute("<whatever arbitrary sql you want")
```

If you're trying to "fetch a row" then you'll have to give it some information about the row you're trying to get:

```
BbOrder.find(45)
will generate:
"select bb_orders.* from bb_orders where id = 45"
and this will return an instance of your BbOrder class.
```

or something more complex:

```
BbOrder.where(:shipped => true)
will generate:
"select bb_orders.* from bb_orders where shipped"
and this will return collection of BbOrder instances where the attribute shipped is true
in other words, a row in the database where the shipped column is true 
corresponds to one BbOrder instance
```

Comment: did you get any help from this?

Comment: I don't understand this naming convention. My table must be named BBOrders. So does that mean I can't use rails? Do I make a bb_orders.rb in the models folder and copy that class?

Comment: And your code assumes I'm connecting to the default sqlite db. I have an external one. How would you connect that with your code?

Comment: You can still use rails, name your model class BbOrders < ActiveRecord::Base, in a file models/bb_order.rb and at the top of the class tell it the table name with self.table_name = "BBOrders"

No, my example does not assume sqlite, in database.yml you can connect to any database you want, the class is agnostic to the database.  Add your database.yml file and I can help you configure it.

Comment: I did, I have all of it. I think I'm not digging in the right direction. When I try to do the query, it shows me that I'm Using my database, but when I query it, it says invalid object name 'orders'. I created an orders table in the database just for testing purposes and followed the naming convention. But it still won't query.

Comment: paste your database.yml above.

Comment: Added. I managed to connect by using the TinyTds::Client call, but I don't think that is very efficient.

Comment: I kind of lack one. I only have the basic ones that you put up and I do the Client call inside a controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need a Gem for that. DBI ODBC Drive might be one of manyoptions available. But try the instructions at this URL (http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/ruby/rails.html#introduction)

The end result will look something like this

`require 'dbi'
    # Replace MY_DSN with the name of your ODBC data
    # source. Replace and dbusername with dbpassword with
    # your database login name and password.
    DBI.connect('dbi:ODBC:MY_DSN', 'dbusername', 'dbpassword') do | dbh |
       # Replace mytable with the name of a table in your database.
       dbh.select_all('select * from mytable') do | row |
          p row
       end
    end`